# SVM - Slack variable

Tags: svm

I understand that in SVM (Support Vector Machines) you can add a slack variable ε to "soften" the borders. Reading from some textbooks, it mentions that ε > 1 will allow the corresponding sample to be misclassified as belonging to the wrong class. So for example if we have:

```
g = yf(x)
```

To be the product between the actual class label (1 or -1) and the model's prediction (a real number) then any correctly classified sample would result in g being positive. (Ie: Either both y and f(x) are positive of they are both negative.

So we can calculate the model's loss as `max(0, 1-g)` where any misclassified sample will result in `1-g > 0` and a positive loss. By adding the ε term we get `max(0,1-g-ε)` which makes the model more tolerant to errors.

However, was does only ε > 1 allow misclassificatoin whereas 0 < ε < 1 only allows samples to trepass the margin while still being correctly classified?

Answer (score 1):

For 0<ξ≤1 1$ the point is between margin and the correct side of hyperplane.

So, ξ/||w||<1/||w||. This is known as margin violation

ξ>1 **only** means misclassification because, ξ/||w||>2/||w||.

Another thing is that the slack variable (ξ) itself means the loss max(0,1−g).

Please refer to [this](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~az/lectures/ml/lect2.pdf) document if you are in doubt.

Note: I have used ξ instead of ϵ to avoid any notation abusement.